# External link to Fancybox popup on page load

Tags: hyperlink, popup, fancybox

Sorry, I have a question a simple question, but I can not figure it out.

I want to make an image popup using Fancybox 2 on page load that works fine, 
but when user clicks on the image popup he should be directed to external link, 
that I can not succeed.

Here is my code:
    `<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".modal_link").fancybox().trigger('click');

    });
    </script>`

and in html: 
    `<a class="modal_link" href="image.PNG"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".modal_link").fancybox({
  closeClick : true, // closes fancybox when clicking INSIDE of it
  afterClose : function(){
   // redirect to a new page after closing fancybox
   window.location = 'http://newsite.com/';
   // parent.location = 'http://newsite.com/'; // also works
  }
 }).trigger('click');
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was not presize, but your example works fine if the link directs to another page, but if I try to link with a subsection in the same page, popup reloads again. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and one more thing that the close button as usually in the corner of popup also works as a link, so the user has no choice to close it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        $.fn.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
    }
});

             </script>
```

Comment: You can help the person on the other end by not pop - ing up every now and then by putting this.
Change fifteendays to oneday and delete *15